# RewriteLog triggers Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to do some debuging on my rewrite rules and wanted to enable RewriteLog to view how they are interpreted.

but when i activate it i get Internal Server Error
heres the line:

```
RewriteLog "/home/solomongaby/www/project/logs/rewrite.log"
```

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`RewriteLog` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) is only allowed in the server or virtual host configuration (see [*Context* value](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context)).

Comment: "It pretty much means what it says. You can't put a RewriteLog directive in an .htaccess file. If you need it, your only option is to put it in the server config or in a virtual host's config section:" http://serverfault.com/questions/96421/why-does-my-rewritelog-not-work

Comment: @PeterEhrlich If people would just read manuals, references, documentations, etc.

Comment: If you have time to learn the system, then sure.  But everything is contextual, and there are directives in the .htaccess that without added context would lead you to believe you can put your logging directives there.  I myself am only here chasing wordpress related rabbits through rabbit holes, and I thank you for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should post whole string from apache log file to be sure, but i suspect that you've tried to add this string in .htaccess and it gives you error "you can't have rewrite log directive here".

P.s. it's

```
RewriteLog "/home/solomongaby/www/project/logs/rewrite.log"
```

and not

```
RewriteLog "/home/solomongaby/www/project/logs/rewrite.log
```

Right?

Comment: the double quote was a typo here ... in my file its corect.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a permissions issue.  Check Apache's error.log file.