# .htaccess tiny url not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I'm trying to get clean url working with my site but I'm having problems

I have followed so many tutorials and I am sure my `.htaccess` file is configured properly.

**.htaccess contents**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

I am running apache on an ubuntu server, the .htaccess is at site root folder, the folder structure looks something like the following:

**Folder structure**

```
/var/www/lim/
/var/www/lim/index.php
/var/www/lim/.htaccess
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Or any other related information you could share would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Diemuzi I'll have a look at my logs

Comment: @Diemuzi There are no errors in relation to the problem I'm having, I get standard errors like `File /var/www/lim/register does not exist`

Comment: What problems do you get if you try to access /lim/index ? A 404? 500?

Comment: can you enable the RewriteLog?

Comment: A 404 page not found, which must mean that .htaccess is not being read

Comment: @jamie0726 I tried enabling a rewrite log in .htaccess, it gave me a nasty 500 internal server error

Comment: @mk_89 unfortuntely rewriteLog cannot be enabled via .htaccess, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673711/rewritelog-triggers-internal-server-error

Comment: Rewrite logging can only be turned on in vhost/server config

Comment: @jamie0726 ok I'll have to look into it, I've noticed that if I tried doing something like `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` in the .htaccess file it works fine, I can only assume there is a problem with the rewrite engine

Comment: Thanks guys, it turns out their was an error in the `apache2/sites-available/default` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, additionally, your .htaccess should rewrite the second path component to be the page parameter to index.php, as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/index.php?page=$2 [L]
```

That way, an URL like `http://yourserver.com/lim/mypage` will become `http://yourserver.com/lim/index.php?page=mypage`.

Answer (score 1):

With .htaccess, you absolutely have to use the RewriteBase directive, e.g.

```
RewriteBase /
```

If the content is located in http://www.yoursite.com/lim subdirectory, you have to use

```
RewriteBase /lim
```

If you omit RewriteBase, the file path gets added during rewrite.

Comment: I assume you add this to the .htaccess file, I've tried both variations neither work.