# How to redirect .htm to non-.htm for a specific domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect something "simple" like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)contact.htm$ https://new-domain.com/contact/ [R=301,L]
```

but this is not working. I have to use the RewriteCond because I am working on a multi-domain instance.

Can someone tell me what is missing or wrong?

**edit**

In addition the .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)contact.htm$ https://new-domain.com/contact/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com [R=301,L]
```

The second redirect is working, but the earlier one not.

Comment: This rule should actually work. Try to debug it by enabling `RewriteLog` and see what trace log you get.

Comment: Hm ok, it seems that my hoster has disabled the RewriteLog because it causes a 500 error :(.

Comment: Ah ok, I can't use it in .htaccess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673711/rewritelog-triggers-internal-server-error. I will try to contact my hoster :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)contact.htm$ https://new-domain.com/contact/ [R=301,L]
```